# Convert Excel Formula to VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please advise how to convert a formula to VBA code

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET((AT2:AT644),ROW(AT2:AT644)-MIN(ROW(AT2:AT644)), ,1)) * (AT2:AT644="6"))
```

i do like this, but question how to use "offset" in current code?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Application.Range.Offset(("AT2:AT644"), Application.Rows("AT2:AT644") - Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.Rows("AT2:AT644")), , 1)) * ("AT2:AT644" = "6"))
```

Thanks,
Regards,
Lure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrated from comment...

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET((AT2:AT644),ROW(AT2:AT644)-MIN(ROW‌​(AT2:AT644)), ,1)) * (AT2:AT644=""6""))")
```

or whichever sheet you need to use, just don't use `Application.Evaluate` unless you want it to always evaluate in the context of the ActiveSheet.